# Notification when a movie is released

Tags: gratis, web-apps, email, reminders

Sometimes I see a movie that I would like to see, but hasn't been released yet. I would like to be able to get a notification just before it comes out.

Features:

- Free - I don't need this service enough to want to pay for it
- Web app
- Email notifications when a film is released
- Notifications for different countries (i.e. what is the Australian release date)

Bonus:

- Optional notifications when the film is released on DVD

Comment: Too bad http://www.moviecron.com/ has disappeared :( Unsure whether http://www.imdb.com/list/watchlist has notifications for different countries.

Comment: Casebash, do you need this as a local solution for installation (if yes, which operating system(s)?), or as a Web app (if yes, is signing up for an account okay?)? Does it have to be gratis?

Comment: For DVD releases, you can set up an alert on Amazon

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Does IMDB watch list provide general release notifications?

Comment: @unor: Great question. I'm looking for a free, web service

Answer (score 2):

You should set up a Google Alert linked to your account: https://www.google.com/alerts

Just type in several strings of text as you expect them to appear on various web sites and tell them to send you an alert to your email and you're ready. You can ask about anything from Movie Titles and new releases to events in the personal life of your favorite movie star.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's a good one, but I don't want too many notifications

Comment: May be you can just sign up to http://www.imdb.com/, create a Watchlist and get notifications then...